# Parallel processing in Python: options and alternative

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocess

I tried joblib, however, I got stuck at setting the processor affinity as explained [here](http://I'm%20running%20joblib%20and%20having%20the%20same%20problem%20as%20[here][1],%20it%20only%20uses%202%20cores%20out%20of%208.%20I%20tried%20setting%20the%20CPU%20affinity%20as%20described%20[here][2].%20I'm%20using%20psutil%20version%205.4.3.%20I%20still%20run%20into%20this%20error:%20%20%20%20%20%20AttributeError:%20'Process'%20object%20has%20no%20attribute%20'set_cpu_affinity'%20%20This%20is%20my%20script:%20%20%20%20%20%20from%20datetime%20import%20datetime%20%20%20%20%20from%20subprocess%20import%20call%20%20%20%20%20%20from%20joblib%20import%20Parallel,%20delayed%20%20%20%20%20import%20multiprocessing%20%20%20%20%20import%20psutil%20%20%20%20%20import%20os%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20startTime%20=%20datetime.now()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pdb_name_list%20=%20[]%20%20%20%20%20for%20filename%20in%20os.listdir('/home/labusr/Documents/python_scripts/Spyder/Refinement'):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20filename.endswith(%22.pdb%22):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pdb_name_list.append(filename)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num_cores%20=%20multiprocessing.cpu_count()%20%20%20%20%20p%20=%20psutil.Process(os.getpid())%20%20%20%20%20p.set_cpu_affinity(range(num_cores))%20%20%20%20%20print(p.get_cpu_affinity())%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20inputs%20=%20range(2)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20strcuture_refine(file_name,i):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print('Refining%20strcuture%20%25s%20round%20%25s......%5Cn'%20%25(file_name,%20i))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20call(['/home/labusr/rosetta/main/source/bin/rosetta_scripts.linuxgccrelease',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-in::file::s',%20'/home/labusr/Documents/python_scripts/Spyder/_Refinement/%25s'%20%25file_name,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-parser::protocol',%20'/home/labusr/Documents/A_asymm_refine.xml',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-parser::script_vars',%20'denswt=35',%20'rms=1.5',%20'reso=4.3',%20'map=/home/labusr/Documents/tubulin_exercise/masked_map_center.mrc',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'testmap=/home/labusr/Documents/tubulin_exercise/mmasked_map_top_centered_resampled.mrc',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-in:ignore_unrecognized_res',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-edensity::mapreso',%20'4.3',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-default_max_cycles',%20'200',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-edensity::cryoem_scatterers',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-beta',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-out::suffix',%20'_%25s'%20%25i,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-crystal_refine'])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print('Time%20for%20refining%20%25s%20round%20%25s%20is:%20%5Cn'%20%25(file_name,%20i),%20datetime.now()%20-%20startTime)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20file_name%20in%20pdb_name_list:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(strcuture_refine)(file_name,i)%20for%20i%20in%20inputs)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401074/python3-joblib-starts-using-multiple-cores-drops-to-single-core%20%20%20[2]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323743/ipython-parallel-not-using-multicore) (the error is shown below along with my script).

Now I want to know if there are other options or alternatives that would allow me to accomplish the same goal, which is to run the same script in parallel, using my 8 cores (in a fashion that resembles GNU parallel).

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'set_cpu_affinity'
```

My script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import call 
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import psutil
import os

startTime = datetime.now()

pdb_name_list = []
for filename in os.listdir('/home/labusr/Documents/python_scripts/Spyder/Refinement'):
   if filename.endswith(".pdb"):     
       pdb_name_list.append(filename)

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
p.set_cpu_affinity(range(num_cores))
print(p.get_cpu_affinity())

inputs = range(2) 

def strcuture_refine(file_name,i):
    print('Refining strcuture %s round %s......\n' %(file_name, i))
    call(['/home/labusr/rosetta/main/source/bin/rosetta_scripts.linuxgccrelease',
          '-in::file::s', '/home/labusr/Documents/python_scripts/Spyder/_Refinement/%s' %file_name,
          '-parser::protocol', '/home/labusr/Documents/A_asymm_refine.xml',
          '-parser::script_vars', 'denswt=35', 'rms=1.5', 'reso=4.3', 'map=/home/labusr/Documents/tubulin_exercise/masked_map_center.mrc', 
          'testmap=/home/labusr/Documents/tubulin_exercise/mmasked_map_top_centered_resampled.mrc',
          '-in:ignore_unrecognized_res',
          '-edensity::mapreso', '4.3',
          '-default_max_cycles', '200',
          '-edensity::cryoem_scatterers',
          '-beta',
          '-out::suffix', '_%s' %i,
          '-crystal_refine'])
    print('Time for refining %s round %s is: \n' %(file_name, i), datetime.now() - startTime)

for file_name in pdb_name_list:
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(strcuture_refine)(file_name,i) for i in inputs)
```

Comment: Your question does not explain why you do not use GNU Parallel. Can you elaborate on that? https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: Actually I can use and did use GNU parallel, but I want to run this script on a remote machine, and I rather handle this using python, and not parallel.

Comment: I believe I can understand wanting to do everything yourself.

But I do not understand why running on a remote machine would be a barrier given https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ Can you specify what stops you from using GNU Parallel on the remote machine?

Comment: It's a server that uses the Slurm workload manager.

Comment: Slurm does not prevent you from using GNU Parallel (do a search for 'slurm gnu parallel' to see how). Are there any other reasons why you do not use GNU Parallel?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to just launch multiple Python processes from e.g. a command line. To make each process handle its own file, you can pass it when invoking Python:

```
python myscript.py filename
```

The passed `filename` is then available in Python via

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: This is too simplistic I'm afraid. I want to program it.

Comment: You could write a bash script which launches the Python processes