# Specify cores in n_jobs sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Sklearn used `n_jobs` parameter in multiple functions. We can pass how many cores we want to use. For example 1 for one core and -1 for all cores. My system has six cores and I want to use [0,1,3,4] cores only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried nor heard about this possibility before, with `scikit-learn`.

Still, as `scikit-learn` [uses](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.register_parallel_backend.html) [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html), it *might* be the right direction, for you to investigate, to start looking for how to implement your custom `ParallelBackendBase`, which is a helper abc that defines all methods a `ParallelBackend` must implement [1](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#custom-backend-api-experimental), [2](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/_parallel_backends.py), [3](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/377); you might be able to implement internally [CPU Affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330197/6365112) to pin a process to a particular CPU core.

Nevertheless, it is purely experimental.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible: you can't specify specific cores, that is up to the system.